# Calculate the integral using Residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Evaluate the integral $$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{\tan(z)}{z^3}dz, \text{ in counterclockwise orentation.}$$

**My approach**

There is only one pole inside $|z|=1$,$z=0$, a pole of order 2.

Using Residue theorem, $$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{\tan(z)}{z^3}dz =2\pi i * \text{ sum of residue inside the contours}$$

$\text{Res}(f(z),z=0) = \lim_{z \to0} \frac{d}{dz}(z-0)^2 \frac{\tan(z)}{z^3}=0$

Adding all residues gives $$\int_{|z|=1} \frac{\tan(z)}{z^3}dz=0$$

My question: Are my calculations right?

Comment: Are you sure that $\pm \pi/2$ are inside the unit circle?

Comment: I have edited the answer.

Comment: @Ian correct me where I am wrong.

Comment: The calculation is correct, the residue is $0$.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the d/dz somehow, ignore me. And yeah, that makes sense because $\tan''$ is zero at $z=0$, so $\tan(z)/z^3$ has no $1/z$ term in its Laurent expansion.